# Dagger2 do not generate Component class in regular Java project (IDEA IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, dagger

Here is the Gradle :

```
plugins {
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.10"
}

group 'hello'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
}
```

And here are the classes :

Component :

```
import dagger.Component;
/**
 * Created by bart on 27/06/2017.
 */

@Component(modules = {MainModule.class})
public interface MainComponent {
    Service myService();

    void inject(Manager aManager);
}
```

When I launch the ./gradlew build in the console, all is compiled OK.
I don't get why I do not have access to DaggerMainComponent class or any Dagger* class in my Manager class.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160956
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150042

Comment: Ok so this i a thing. Anyway, i finish using Android Studio for my tests, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Annotation Processor is turned on. 
**File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processor**
Click on "**Enable annotation processor** and choose **obtain processors from project classpath**

and here is what my .gradle file looks like

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'net.ltgt.apt-idea' version "0.15"
}

group 'DaggerExample'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.23.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.23.2'

}
```

This is all what necessary to make dagger run.